# Jekyll -- gems need two different versions of sitemap?

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to install a Jekyll theme gem called "alembic-jekyll-theme". I tried to run a bundle update and received the following:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "jekyll-sitemap":
  In Gemfile:
    alembic-jekyll-theme (~> 3.1) was resolved to 3.1.0, which depends on
      jekyll-sitemap (~> 0.13)

    github-pages was resolved to 203, which depends on
      jekyll-sitemap (= 1.4.0)
```

What am I supposed to do when a theme and GitHub pages require two different versions? How would I go about updating the version number of "jekyll-sitemap"?

Answer (score 0):

GitHub Pages does not support custom themes directly as gems. If you want to use GitHub Pages with a custom theme that is not directly included in your source code, you'll need to [install the theme as a remote theme](https://github.blog/2017-11-29-use-any-theme-with-github-pages/). In your case, [follow the steps in the Alembic theme README to install it as a remote theme](https://github.com/daviddarnes/alembic#as-a-github-pages-remote-theme).

If you don't intend to use GitHub Pages, then do not install the `gh-pages` gem, and just [install Alembic as a Jekyll theme](https://github.com/daviddarnes/alembic#as-a-jekyll-theme).